# How do I connect to Astra DB from Pentaho Data Integration?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

I would like to connect to my Astra DB from [Pentaho Data Integration](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.1/Products/Pentaho_Data_Integration) (PDI also known as "Spoon", formerly KETTLE). How do I configure PDI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prerequisites

This article assumes you have installed [Pentaho Data Integration](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.1/Products/Pentaho_Data_Integration) on your laptop or PC. It was written for version 9.1 on MacOS but these instructions should also work for the Windows version of PDI.

You will also need to [generate an application token](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/managing-org.html#_manage_application_tokens) and [download the secure bundle](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/secure-connect-bundle.html) for [your Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf).

### Procedure

##### JDBC DRIVER

Download the JDBC driver from the DataStax website:

STEP A1 - Go to https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers.

STEP A2 - Select **Simba JDBC Driver for Apache Cassandra**.

STEP A3 - Select **JDBC 4.2**.

STEP A4 - Read the license terms and accept it (click the checkbox).

STEP A5 - Hit the blue **Download** button.

STEP A6 - Once the download completes, unzip the downloaded file.

##### IMPORT DRIVER

Deploy the Simba driver to Pentaho servers using the distribution tool:

STEP B1 - On your laptop or PC, copy the Simba JAR to the JDBC distribution directory:

```
$ cp CassandraJDBC42.jar pentaho/jdbc-distribution/
```

STEP B2 - Run the distribution tool (`distribute-files.bat` on Windows):

```
$ cd /Applications/Pentaho/jdbc-distribution
$ ./distribute-files.sh CassandraJDBC42.jar
```

STEP B3 - Verify that the JAR has been copied to the PDI library:

```
$ cd /Applications/Pentaho
$ ls -lh design-tools/data-integration/lib/CassandraJDBC42.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 erick  vaxxed   16M 14 Sep 22:18 design-tools/data-integration/lib/CassandraJDBC42.jar
 
$ file design-tools/data-integration/lib/CassandraJDBC42.jar
design-tools/data-integration/lib/CassandraJDBC42.jar: Java archive data (JAR)
```

STEP B4 - Restart Pentaho on your workstation for the Simba driver to be loaded.

##### NEW CONNECTION

Connect to your Astra DB in PDI:

STEP C1 - Create a new Transformation.

STEP C2 - Open a new **Database Connection** dialog box.

STEP C3 - In the **Connection name** field, give your DB connection a name.

STEP C4 - Under **Connection type**, select `Generic database`.

STEP C5 - Set the **Custom connection URL** to:

```
jdbc:cassandra://;AuthMech=2;TunableConsistency=6;SecureConnectionBundlePath=/path/to/secure-connect-getvaxxed.zip
```

Note that you will need to specify the full path to your secure bundle.

STEP C6 - Set the **Custom driver class name** field to `com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver`.

STEP C7 - In the **Username** field, enter the string `token`.
STEP C8 - In the **Password** field, paste the value of the token you created in the **Prerequisites** section above. The token value looks like `AstraCS:AbC...XYz:123...edf0`.

[image]

STEP C9 - Click on the **Test Connection** button to confirm that the driver configuration is working:

[image]

STEP C10 - Click on the **OK** button to save the connection settings.

### Final test

Connect to your Astra DB by launching the SQL Editor in Pentaho and run a simple CQL statement. For example:

[image]

Here's an example output:

[image]

You should also be able to browse the keyspaces in your Astra DB using the DataBase Explorer. Here's an example output:

[image]

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!